# How do I retrieve a users' last 5 posts?

Tags: posts, author, users

How do I retrieve a particular users last 5 blog posts?

Currently, I am trying the following approach, but it seems that it is retrieving the actual post titles and permalinks:

```
<?php
    $allUsers = get_users('orderby=post_count&order=DESC');
?>
```

When I do a `var_dump` on `$allUsers` I see a lot of information (including username and password info).  I am looking specifically for the titles of the posts they have written along with the permalinks for those posts.

Comment: Are you trying to get it from specific users or all users? I think you want to use [`get_posts()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) ordered by `post_date`

Comment: Basically, I am just trying to A) get a list of all users who have written posts (so, basically any author with at least one post)  and B) out of those users, one will be picked by a user in the dashboard in order to display the selected author's 5 recent posts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, when you want get posts, you should think about `WP_Query`. It's already in the docs for your question.

You can get posts by an author like this

```
$query = new WP_Query( array(
    'author' => AUTHOR_ID,
    'posts_per_page' => 5
) );
```

You can even get posts by more than one author, like this

```
$query = new WP_Query( array(
    'author__in' => array( AUTHOR_ID, ANOTHER_AUTHOR_ID ), 
    'posts_per_page' => 5
) );
```

Because WP_Query is sort by date and order descending by default so you don't need specify that information.